# I found a problem when updating data from PHP to my SQL database I want to update according to student ID

Tags: php, mysql

[image]
Here is my code:

```
function mark_update($lesson_id='', $student_id=''){
if ($this->session->userdata('admin_login') != 1)
redirect('login', 'refresh');
$data['status']                  = $this->input->post('status');
$data['uploader_type']          =   $this->session->userdata('
$data['uploader_id']            =   $this->session->userdata('
$data['year']                   =   $this->db->get_where('settings',array('type'=>'running_year'))- 
>row()->
$data['timestamp']              =   strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
$this->db->update('assessment', $data);
redirect(base_url().'index.php?admin/mark_upload/'.$lesson_id.'/'.$student_id , 'refresh');
}
```

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: You have neither asked a question, nor described a problem

Comment: $data = array( 
    'name'      => $_POST['name'] , 
    'groupname' => $_POST['groupname'], 
    'age'       => $_POST['age']
);

$this->db->where('id', $_POST['id']);

$this->db->update('tbl_user', $data);

Comment: @ShafiqulIslam I tried it but 'Unknown column 'assessment_id' in 'where clause..' Sir, what's the solution??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this will help you, Update your data and run this

```
$data = array(
'status'      => $this->input->post('status'),
'uploader_type' => "yourdata",
'year'       => "year"
);
$this->db->where('student_id', $student_id);

$this->db->update('assessment', $data);
```

You can need to change this code as which you want

```
function mark_update($lesson_id='', $student_id=''){
$data = array(
'status'      => $this->input->post('status'),
'uploader_type' => "yourdata",
'year'       => "year"
);
$this->db->where('student_id', $student_id);

$this->db->update('assessment', $data);
}
```

If you want to update by assessment_id then update your function like this

```
function mark_update($lesson_id='', $assessment_id=''){
$data = array(
'status'      => $this->input->post('status'),
'uploader_type' => "yourdata",
'year'       => "year"
);
$this->db->where('assessment_id', $assessment_id);

$this->db->update('assessment', $data);
}
```

Comment: Sir, only 1 number is entered, what if number 2 aka Active is not active ?              <option><?php echo get_phrase('Select'); ?></option>
<?php $mark_status = $this->db->get('assessment' , array('status' =>$row['status']))->row()->status;?>
<option value="1" <?php if($mark_status == '1') echo 'selected';?>><?php echo get_phrase('Active');?>
</option>
<option value="2"<?php if($mark_status == '2') echo 'selected';?>><?php echo get_phrase('Inactive');?>
</option>

Comment: Update 'status'      => 1 , to 'status'  = $this->input->post('status');

but i did not found any post data in your function , i added this for demo code so you need to update as which you want

Comment: $data = array(
'status'        => $this->input->post('status'),
'timestamp'     => strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s")),
'uploader_id'   => $this->session->userdata('login_user_id'),
'uploader_type' => $this->session->userdata('login_type'),
'year'          => $this->db->get_where('settings',array('type'=>'running_year'))->row()->description,
);
$this->db->where('assessment_id', $assessment_id);
$this->db->update('assessment', $data);

Comment: ok this code works. thank you..
but I want to change student_id to assessment_id and not work Unknown column 'assessment_id' in 'where clause'. What is the way out, sir?
Sorry I asked a lot : D

Comment: If you want to update by assessment_id then update this code

$this->db->where('student_id', $student_id);

to 

$this->db->where('assessment_id', $student_id);

If you want to also update by assessment_id then need to pass assessment_id in your function 

and final code will be

$this->db->where('assessment_id', $assessment_id);

Comment: when I change 'student _id', $ student _id to 'assessment _id', $ assessment _id, an error occurs
(Unknown column 'assessment_id' in 'where clause'
UPDATE `assessment` SET` status` = '2', `timestamp` = 1574918941,` uploader_id` = '1', `uploader_type` = 'admin',` year` = '2019-2020' WHERE `assessment_id` IS NULL )
And I want to change the ID according to Primary
I have tried to find a tutorial with the same error. but does not work :(